# How to solve memory heap error ts-node-dev?

Tags: heap-memory, ts-node, ts-node-dev

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

During development, memory heap errors keep coming up and development is delayed.
I set node memory to prevent this, but I don't know if it worked.

```
        "predev": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=12000",
        "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --no-notify --rs src/index.ts --env=dev",
```

In case .env may reset this, I put it in the .env file as well.

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=12000
```

The same symptoms appear over and over again.
I think, i should at least check if the memory is expanded or not. But don't know how...
What should I do ?

Comment: Was this problem solved. I am interested to know the solution.

Comment: @Ashwin it is not solved. I am still suffering.